# Crash analytic surge up when runner running testcases

Tags: python, sentry

**Background:**
I am using Django2 and Sentry for detecting my crash. In my gitlab pipe line. I used to has `test` job as a major concern to not break any features when deploy new feature.

Many of my `testcases` contains `Exception` and `Sentry` does surge up.

**Question:**

Do I have any technique to suppress sentry for a while during `pipeline` running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well basically if there is a settings.py configuration that specify whether to send errors to Sentry, you could create a different one for test environment and turn off sentry logging.
I currently use a separate test_settings.py file where I remove sentry (and related) from the INSTALLED_APPS. It works well enough for us.

Comment: Home come I forgot this! Thank you